# How can i return 404 error without change url in Vue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, http-status-code-404, vue-router

> Question

Using Vue.js, how can i return 404 error in dynamic route without change url?

> Part of my route.js (everything ok)

```
{

    path: '/work/:id',
    name: 'work',
    component: () => import( './views/Work.vue' )

},

{

    path: '*',
    name: 'NotFound',
    component: () => import( './views/NotFound.vue' )

}
```

> Part of Work.vue component. Where i check if route param are in my static json, if not, open NotFound component before route enter

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
        vm.item = json.find(item => item.id == vm.$route.params.id)

        if(!vm.item) {
            next({name: NotFound})
        }

    })
}
```

> The problem

When i try **site.com/work/non-existent-id**, the component "NotFound" open, but the url goes from **site.com/work/non-existent-id** to **site.com**

> What I espect

**site.com/work/non-existent-id** open component "NotFound" and the url stays at **site.com/work/non-existent-id**

> Example

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/something - return 404 error and stay in url

Answer (score 0):

Routers are designed to do exactly what you are wanting them to not do.  If you want to display some content on any route in your application, I would recommend creating a new component and maybe firing off an event to show whatever content you want.

Personally, I would think re-routing would be the way to go because this will allow the user to hit the back button in the browser to get back to where they came from, but I guess that all depends on your specific use case here.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still using vue router3 and works for me without changing the url.
for axios.

```
beforeRouteEnter(to,from,next) {
 axios
 .get(`http://localhost:5000/api/product/${to.params.id}`)
 .then((res) => {
    next((vm) => {
      vm.product = res.data;
      next();
    });
  })
  .catch((error) => {
     
      next({ name: 'notFound', params: [to.path]});
    
    
  });
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).